# make a virtual host of laravel project

Tags: php, apache, laravel, wamp

I made the necessary edit to the "httpd-vhosts" and i knew that i should add the directory "\public" if it was laravel project.

```
<Directory C:\wamp\myproject\public>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\myproject\public" 
ServerName myproject.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but the problem is that it only work for myproject.com .. it doesn't work for "myproject.com/login" for example .. it redirects to the url "http://localhost:8000/login" .. is there something i should edit in the project itself ? or in the file "httpd-vhosts"?

**edit**
the problem was in the code of the forms .. it's action was "http://localhost:8000/login" not "/login" .. everything is working now after fixing it.

Comment: What error you get when it does not work?

Comment: "This webpage is not available" .. it's probably because i didn't do the "php artisan serve" .. but this is not the problem .. the problem is that it redirects to "localhost:8000/login" not "myproject.com/login"

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have not enabled module rewrite and that is why the routing fails.

If you are using xampp then you can find the instructions from here http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/